# logger timestamp does not change when receiving messages from PIPE in apache

Tags: apache, logging

I

am trying to send data to a syslog server.  However, the message seem to have a timestamp of the time that the apache was started.  From tcpdump, i see the following:

> 17:18:53.254129 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28157, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 221)
> myhost.35679 > syslog.foo.com.syslog: [udp sum ok] SYSLOG, length: 193
> Facility local6 (22), Severity error (3)
> Msg: **Mar  3 15:42:11** foobarclient  httpd: 1.1.1.1 - xxxxx [03/Mar/2023:**17:18:53 **+0000] POST /cmd/system/foo.php "" HTTP/2.0 200 240 13 "" "-" "-" "-" 1293 592 "xxxxx"\0x0a

Notice the message from httpd-access log has a timestamp of 17:18:53, but the syslog message has 15:42:11 which is when the apache server was startd.

My config file has
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b" common

```
CustomLog "| /usr/bin/logger -h 10.10.10.25 -thttpd -plocal6.err" common
```

Any suggestions
Thanks in advance

thise should be simple enough.... Only thing i did was to add a severity -plocal6.info to the mix.

Comment: Are your syslog and apache configured on the same timezone?

Comment: They are though I cannot confirm the remote syslog server as I don't have access.  My server is set to UTC. Using tcpdump, I can see every syslog message is prepended with the exact same timestamp ( that being the start time of the apache server).  The content of the message accurately reflects the timestamp of the data in the apache log.

Comment: Note that this looks more like a problem with logger as when i remove the target and have logger interact with syslog-ng the timestamp is correct